# Migrating from Google App Engine to Heroku (missing YAML)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku

Overnight hack, trying to create an environment where GAE code (using Python libs/packages) could be easily ported over to Heroku with minimal editing.

**EDIT**
Q: YAML offers static file sharing with only 3 lines of code, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this file sharing with _minimal_editing_ (keyword).

For example, to share the 'static/' folder. One solution is to implement a number of classes found in http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/file-example.html - not an elegant answer.

The big picture is to empower the developer with the freedom of choice to choose a (hopefully) better/cheaper cloud provider, follow steps 1,2,3...  and the app will be up and running with minimal fuss. Hope this clears up the confusion.

---

In case anyone inquires, my code is as follows...

The "**main.py**" file:

```
import jinja2
import webapp2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))


class HelloWebapp2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = { 'test': 'Hello World!!'}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('jinja2_test.html')
        return self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


app2 = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HelloWebapp2)
], debug=True)

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    httpserver.serve(app2, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the "**requirements.txt**" file:

```
Jinja2==2.6
webapp2==2.3
paste==1.7.5.1
webob==1.1.1
```

The output file "**templates/jinja2_test.html**":

```
{{test}}
```

The default "**procfile**":

```
web: python main.py
```

Comment: You haven't actually described what problem you're having. Have you looked at TyphoonAE?

Comment: Voting to close unless you can describe what the actual problem is.  So far you have told us what you are doing, but not what is going wrong.  You also might want to explain what your ultimate goal is, as I suspect that writing your own python app engine runtime from scratch is not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on TyhoonAE, this new to me.

Comment: I think one of us is confused about what YAML.  As far as I know, YAML is a simple standard for formatting text files in an easy to parse way.  I don't see how that relates to implementing static file sharing.

Comment: @Peter-Recore: See: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers - above it is Static Directory Handlers. Used within GAE to "makes it easy to serve the entire contents of a directory as static files".

Comment: Yes, the config files for Static Directory handlers happen to be in YAML format.  So are you trying to learn how to parse YAML, or are are you trying to learn how to make a web server that serves static files?

Comment: Learning how to work without YAML on foreign land..err cloud. With Cloud services heating up, won't you want the leisure to check-in and check out at a whim?. Coin a new term: "Cloud Hopping".

Comment: Why would you close this issue? Its quite pertinent and is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is serving static pages using Django on Heroku.

collectstatic seems to be the right answer for this:
web: python my_django_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_app/settings.py

http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

On heroku platform, with high volume apps you're supposed to use amazon s3 for static asset storage: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

For development purposes I created a simple "catch all" handler (it should be the last handler in the list) that serves static files that end with certain suffixes from the project directory. Adding this is quite simple. But remember, it's not very effective, and it's a waste of the web dynos resources.

```
import webapp2
import re
import os

class FileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self,path):

    if re.search('html$',path):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html' 
    elif re.search('css$',path):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/css' 
    elif re.search('js$',path):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/javascript' 
    elif re.search('gif$',path):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/gif' 
    elif re.search('png$',path):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png' 
    else:
      self.abort(403)
    try:
      f=open("./"+path,'r')
    except IOError:
      self.abort(404)
    self.response.write(f.read())
    f.close

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/(.*)', FileHandler),
], debug=True)

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
    httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Great answer, just bypass the issue altogether. I have used Amazon S3 to store thousands of static files, serving over 10,000+ monthly (Mar 2013) users in Facebook