# AWS vs Heroku vs something else for scalable platform?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability

Considering you're a startup with no funds for own server farm. Which existing solution can give you a peace of mind that any sudden increase in traffic won't bring everything down.

I know it's not just up to hardware, so we plan to have at least a load balancer, memcache and  few db servers.

Is it possible to have a setup on AWS that would automatically add instances and bandwidth if the traffic increases?

What other advice you could give to deployment noobs? Thanks.

ps: I apologize in advance if a question is too broad or reflects inexperience on mentioned topics, but that's why I ask.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Heroku. Because you're a start-up, keep things lean and it doesn't get leaner than almost free (with 1 dyno + small shared DB). Spend time building your product, not on the infrastructure. You don't want to be installing patches when you should be talking to customers. Heroku is also flexible and allows you to scale up 'dynos' as your traffic increases so no worries about growing there. Heroku won't scale automatically for you, though, so do your own server monitoring. Heroku add-ons are also nice.

Comment: So you're saying there's more hassle and more cost involved with AWS?

Comment: Definitely. AWS is Infrastructure-as-a-Service, which means you get access to the hardware and that's it. It's up to you to configure the OS, install software, and maintain it. Heroku is Platform-as-a-Service: they add value by handling all the sysadmin tasks for you.

Comment: Definitely Heroku. With AWS you have to get into the nitty gritty of installing services, configuring, securing your server etc and being a DBA. Heroku takes all of that away so you can just concentrate on your application.

Comment: Ok, any alternatives to Heroku?

Comment: For example, having two dedicated servers on Webfaction or something similar?

Comment: Also, Heroku does seem a bit expensive. With $200 for DB, 3 web dynos, 1 worker dyno, some add ons, it quickly comes to $400.

Comment: Well, there's always tension between money and time. Got money? - pay an expert and save time. Got time? - DIY and save money. Yes, Heroku does get expensive in the higher end. But hopefully you'll have proved your business model and earning income by the time you need 4 dynos. You can always move off Heroku later if there are better choices. Just curious, what are you building that requires so much resources in the start-up phase?

Comment: Besides, 2 Webfaction dedicated servers will cost you at least $700/month.

Comment: Should be reminded Heroku does not provide any Customer service or direct support.

Comment: I'm in the same ballpark right now... I'm comparing heroku to alwaysdata... any suggestions??

Comment: Surprised no one mentioned bitnami for EC2. installs everything for you with a click

Answer (score 4):

Recently we have done a very good comparison between AWS and Heroku and we decided to move to Heroku, here is the detail of this http://www.confiz.com/blog/tech-session/selecting-the-right-cloud-platform/

Comment: I don't understand why you say you "decided to move to Heroku" and linked to a presentation that says "Suggested Architecture: Two (or more) Geographically spread EC2 instances for Application layer with Xeround for Database Layer".  Would you please explain?

Comment: This presentation was given to client (little outdated) so thats why presentation is showing suggested architecture.

Comment: @Gull the given link is broken!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Python, you can try [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).

Migrating the Python app from one platform to another isn't [too difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985926/migrating-from-google-app-engine-to-heroku-missing-yaml) once you get the past the learning curve as to what features is (not) available. GAE offers datastore, memcache, blobstore plus a few other goodies like dJango and Jinja (templating). Worth checking the [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html) start page and it didn't take me long to integrate it into Facebook and Dropbox too.

Comment: I heard from a developer who is very proficient in Python and in deployment, that GAE was a nightmare. It wasn't that recent though, maybe things changed in the meantime. For example I heard that ORM is not available, is that true?

Comment: GAE uses [LevelDB](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/07/google-open-sources-nosql-data.php) which is a noSQL database. A number of restrictions to acheive blinding fast queries.

Comment: GAE is horrible, I am spending too much time in downloading libs that are not in GAE and not on my application logic, after this app, I will never try to work on GAE

Comment: Amazon EC2 requires linux system admin skills, GAE requires lots of API read-up (and understanding). After over 2 years on both platform, I would choose Amazon EC2 when I need greater control of the server (eg: URL rewrite, video & image manipulation) and GAE for quick apps.

Comment: are you aware of the fact that GAE also charges for reads and writes? that heroku doesnt

Answer (score 4):

Stay away from Heroku. You can get EC2 for free for a year from Amazon. Scaling up heroku is extremely costly. Their pricing tends to be unclear and their customer service in general sucks.

Comment: Can you please provide details, references, or examples to corroborate your claims?

Comment: More details needed. My experience with their customer service has been excellent. Their pages make their pricing very clear.

Comment: The project may never get to the point of scaling up if time and money resources are wasted on configuring and maintaining an IaaS like EC2  :)

Comment: Heroku runs Amazon EC2 in the backdrop, specifically Ubuntu 10.04 and I have encountered latency issues amongst others. If you have Linux skills, use Amazon EC2 or you prefer (mostly) FREE service, use Google App Engine. I have migrated a few clients away from Heroku last year.

Comment: Amazon throttles the CPU on micro instances if CPU usage is high for more than a few minutes. This micro instances unsuitable for production except for very small sites.

Comment: yeah Heroku is buggy and their pricing is not clear

Answer (score 2):

BitNami for Amazon EC2 includes ready-to-run versions of Apache, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Python, Django, Git, their required dependencies, and much more. It can be deployed via all-in-one free native installers, virtual machines and Cloud Images. maybe worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience is that you should generally start with Heroku. Get your app out in the wild and find that product/market-fit or some type of traction. You will know you are going somewhere because customers will cause scaling issues. In this case, Heroku will allow you to scale with very little overhead. And for some time, this scaling will not hit you in the wallet.

Jump to AWS when you are ready. When will you be ready? When you have enough pain, in the wallet, where you need more control over the stack. You can hire a AWS devops type or learn about it, yourself.

Both Heroku and AWS have auto-scaling solutions, but whereas Heroku has a fairly flat learning curve -- that is what you are paying for -- AWS can get broad and steep fairly quickly. A Udemy AWS course or any of the hundred other online resources will get your started down building a robust AWS architecture.

Lastly, while performance should not be your primary concern, make sure that you are using best practices in your code. Your first user should not bring your system to a crawl. And AWS will not help if she does.

Hope this helps in some way.

This has been my experience. My saas start kits are built to deploy to Heroku out of the box for this reason. However, the start kits are also containerized. I know that you spoke of AWS explicitly, but with containers you can be infrastructure agnostic. This is worth considering!

Ted [at] https://stacksimple.io

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog series I'm starting because I found Heroku to not be scalable at all from a financial perspective compared to EC2 and Digital Ocean. Going to be showing how to put a Ruby application on Digital Ocean using Docker, which allows you the same flexibility and ability to scale up and down very quickly https://medium.com/@karimbutt/weaning-off-heroku-part-1-b7f123ae855f

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depeneds whether you're looking for a PaaS, IaaS or SaaS, and what is the language you using.

- AWS is a IAAS/PAAS with multiple components and layers.
- Heroku is a PAAS supporting multiple languages, most notably Java, Ruby and Node.js

Other platforms come into play depending on your needs, you might want to take a look at this comparison as well: https://dictativ.com/compare/paas