# Should I keep a business process management application running on Google App Engine, or switch to a more normal platform

Tags: java, .net, google-app-engine, architecture

I'm currently developing a roadmap for a business management platform currently running on Google App Engine that performs the following tasks:

1. Reads information via the Google Docs API to pickup submissions to a Google form. The form is used for user to apply to become part of a mentoring programme. (The timeouts and request limits can sometimes be a bit tricky with things like this)
2. Performs a matching/weighting algorithm against the questions in the spreadsheet, so that applicants can be matched to each other. These weightings are now stored in the db as to give control if the spreadsheet changes
3. If a user is matched a series of emails are sent, and various API's are used to give the users access to various Google services (all users must signup with a Gmail address)
4. Requires users to login on a monthly basis to report how they are performing as part of the mentoring programme, the system then calculates a performance score for their mentoring relationship.

There are some obvious improvements to be made, such as swapping some of the flexibility of the Google forms for good validation and the ability to save your progress (it is a massive form) but aside from clear upgrades like this, is GAE the right platform for an app like this.

**Here are the advantages to GAE**

- Uptime
- No Manual Server management
- Scaleability (although it is unlikely this app will ever need scale beyond about 1500 users a month, hitting it infrequently)
- Basically free at this level of traffic

**Disadvantages to GAE**

- Not Great IDE Debug Support (please correct me if wrong, I'm using NetBeans + Python, I know it's possible, but it seems a bit hacky)
- No dedicated Data Management tool (annoying to bring down live data for local testing, and vice versa) No automated backup of Data incase of application damage.
- Currently running Django on App Engine, is there a risk that this might break in future with a new version of GAE?

I'm not sure I've discussed all the issues. The crux of the question is this:

For this kind of application does it make sense to switch to a more standard business platform like .Net or Java, or is the investment in this existing platform (~£70,000) mean that switching is only to be done if absolutely necessary?

Essentially, I feel that having an application like this, which is only going to get more complex could benefit from a more standard application stack, where as GAE is designed for relatively simple web-app things (twitter, http://www.historypin.com/)

However, I would never ever want to re-invent the wheel, and GAE provides lots of benefit from the reduced management overhead.

Comment: Your app sounds very well suited to running on App Engine. Your reasons to switch, too, seem pretty speculative - would you really seriously consider investing thousands of dollars of time to switch based on any of them?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's OK, I guess I just would like a large development community, data editor and support. I see they do offer a $500 a month support option, and they may be possible. I'm also looking into the pydev eclipse route which seems to have come on quite a bit.

Comment: Seeing your job position, can you give any advice on when there might be a simpler way to manage App Engine DataStores? Also my DataStore Admin page is constantly blank at the moment, which I'm trying to use to transfer data between instances.

Answer (score 1):

My 2-cents worth of comment: *Keep using GAE*. On disadvantages:

1. Agreed. Code with `try-catch-finally` (or `except` in Python) and `logging.info` helps.
2. In appengine console, under `datastore admin` link, you can `Copy to Another App` (unsure if your app will stop during the process). Makes it easier to test your modified code on cloned data without affecting the live app or users.
3. New version requires minimal changes (as of writing) on standard Python2.7 libs, however if you are using a fair number of Google APIs, you'd need to update your APIs to the newer v3.0 methods. The structure remains the same though.

I'd also like to add that with Google API, this makes GAE more versatile than other platform out there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and yes as I was writing the above post I am now pretty firmly staying in the camp of sticking with GAE. My backup is that say something just can't be done on app engine, then I'll build a tiny supporting app on another platform (most likely ASP.NET MVC via Azure) which can then have work outsourced to it if needed. Hopefully that will never be needed, but it seems like a way to keep confidence high for the future.

Comment: Heroku is the environment that closely matches GAE's Python and its quite easy to install libraries not supported by GAE. My [findings on porting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985926/migrating-from-google-app-engine-to-heroku-missing-yaml) from GAE, in case you are interested.

Comment: With Google's new exorbitant pricing, you may want check your `billing quota` and explore other cloud providers as a back-up solution.

Comment: I'm currently using PyCharm and pretty impressed so far. However the server running in debug mode is painfully slow, just doing a single crud operation can take 20-30 seconds to reload the page. Should it be that slow?

Comment: It seems each of the static resources being request for the page each take ages to be returned, sequentially. Aside form this the main request is still painful, ~3.3 secs just for a really simple db operation, what gives?

Comment: Just tried in non debug local, still seems pretty slow. Live is fast (as you'd hope for a single crud op!), but locally makes testing painful!